# Question about germs.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Qing Liu's book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, the germs are defined as follows. Let $$ \mathcal{F}_x = \varinjlim_{U \ni x} \mathcal{F}(U). $$

Let $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$. For any $x \in U$, we denote the image of $s$ in $\mathcal{F}_x$ by $s_x$ and call $s_x$ the germ of $s$ at $x$. My question is: what is the image of  $s$ in $\mathcal{F}_x$? What is the map from $\mathcal{F}(U)$ to $\mathcal{F}_x$ explicitly? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's the equivalence class of $s$ modulo the equivalence relation $a\sim b \iff (\exists W)(a\lvert_W = b\lvert_W)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [the wikipedia page about direct limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) and as both commentators already pointed out, the direct limit of the $\mathcal F(U)$ will be $\left.\coprod_{U\ni x } \mathcal F(U)\middle/ \sim\right.$ where $f\sim g$ if and only if $f|_W=g|_W$ for some $W$ on which both $f$ and $g$ are defined. The map from $\mathcal F(U)$ to $\mathcal F_x$ maps $f\in\mathcal F(U)$ to its equivalence class.

Comment: Dear Jesko, You want either a disjoint union or direct sum (depending on exactly how you phrase things) in the definition of the direct limit (wikipedia has a disjoint union), not a direct product.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Fixed! Thanks!